# SUPEE-10570 and Foreign Key Constraint Error

Tags: magento-1.9, database, soap-api-v2, supee-10570

Last night I installed SUPEE 10570 and today we're seeing numerous errors in our Celigo connector that syncs item updates from NetSuite over to Magento via Web Services.  In particular, it's failing when trying to update Upsell Skus.  The error is:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`mydatabase`.`catalog_product_link`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_LNK_LNKED_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`linked_product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity`
>   (`entity_id`) O)

Since this is a new issue and it's now so prolific I'm concerned it's related to the security patch.  I know the patch did touch on a number of core files but I couldn't identify any change that may cause this.  Has anyone else had similar issues and/or can point me in the right direction?

**== EDIT ==**

Adding FK info from DB

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'value_pet_supplies' AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'catalog_product_entity' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'linked_product_id';
+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME           | COLUMN_NAME       | CONSTRAINT_NAME                                  | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME  | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME |
+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| catalog_product_link | linked_product_id | FK_CAT_PRD_LNK_LNKED_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID | catalog_product_entity | entity_id              |
+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I am sure it does not occur from security patch.  i think linked_product_id is not available in catalog_product_entity. can you please check and confirm

Comment: the FK exists, I've updated my question to include it.